# Adding two different rules to htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a rule in my .htaccess file to force www to the URL.
Here is the rule

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

And I am trying to add another rule to remove index.php in the URL.
Here is the other rule

```
#To remove /index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried different ways, changing the order of the rules, removing [L] option, I have the first rule working but not the second, I am not sure what I am missing.
Any help and guidance would really be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: So... with what url did you test that rule?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The first rule is working if I keep the index.php in my urls. But when I removed the index.php from the entire application, the first rule is not working, that means when I type "example.com" in the url bar it is supposed  to become "www.example.com", but it is staying as "example.com"